# How can I construct a Python string that is 16 bytes long?

Tags: python, string, byte, pycrypto

When I make a Python string of one character, i.e.

```
txt = "h"
```

and I check its size, I get

```
import sys
sys.getsizeof(txt)
34
```

If one character is 34 bytes, how do I make a String of 16 byes?

P.S. I'm playing around with [PyCrypto AES, in OFB Mode](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/), which required input of 16 bytes

Comment: create an array of bytes, not a string

Comment: sizeof includes the object header which shouldn't matter at all. Now if you're using python3, getting an exact bytecount is still non-trivial (encoding changes depending on the content of the string) but then again, if you're not working on byte arrays for encryption you're doing it wrong.

Comment: a string that is 16 characters long is said to be 16 bytes (in python2) ... python3 changes some things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getsizeof` does not return the actual size of the string but it accounts for additional garbage collector overhead.
As shown bellow `test` starts as an empty string but memory allocated for it is not zero due to reasons listed above.

```
>>> test = ""
>>> sys.getsizeof(test)
37
>>> test = "" + "h"
>>> sys.getsizeof(test)
38
>>> test = "" + "h" + "h"
>>> sys.getsizeof(test)
39
>>>
```

To create a 16 bytes string, one way would be:

```
>>> test = " " * 16
>>> sys.getsizeof(test)
53
```

53 - 37 = 16 bytes

Answer (score 4):

`sys.getsizeof(obj)` returns the size of the object including internal values. This contains more than the characters or bytes of a string.

If you want to know how long a `bytes` object or a `str` is, then you can call `len(byteString)` or `len(string)`.

I'm assuming that you want to use generate a random IV or key. This can be done in this way:

```
from Crypto import Random
iv = Random.new().read(16)
```

This invokes a CSPRNG if the system has enough entropy. You can also use `AES.block_size` instead of `16`.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6273618) for differences between bytes and str between Python 2 and Python 3.